# Printing in (Parallel Port) Dot Matrix over C#

Tags: c#-3.0, printing, parallel-port, dot-matrix

For the needs of a project, i want to print over the LPT1 in specific locations, this will print a document in a dot matrix printer where i should print values in the places they should go. I really hate going back, and i don't have any idea where to start. Internet has no specific information about printing in LPT port with C# and especially how to send the values in specific locations while printing. Is there any good example? tutorial for this? would be a life savior.

Comment: Are there actually consumer systems sold today that still have parallel ports?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are still business documents need to be printed in those printers :( But actually this is happening to support the old way too....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could suggest one thing to make your life easier, install a generic text printer driver (this comes as standard) and set that to the LPT1 port. Then you can simply open 'LPT1' and send [escape code](http://webpages.charter.net/dperr/links/esc_p2.htm) sequences to specify font type (bold/italic), emphasized, font pitch etc. I don't know if the resources would be required. But I would imagine it would be something like this:

```cs
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\.\LPT1"))
{
    sr.Write(0x1b);
    sr.Write('k');
    sr.Write('1');
    sr.Write("Hello"); // print in Sans Serif
    sr.WriteLine();
    sr.Flush();
}
```

Resources:

- Printing to a [zebra printer](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/VBNET/printing-to-a-zebra-printer-from-vb-net) using VB.NET (This can be easily translated to C# or compile it to a DLL and reference it in your C# project)
- An article on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823179) on how to interface to LPT1
- Here is an extensive list of info pertaining to [Parallel Port](https://web.archive.org/web/20121214030053/http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm). (look further down near the section titled 'Programming Tools for Port I/O and Interrupts'), discussing the usage of this DLL called inpout32.
- Here is another article on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;322090) that shows how to do raw printing.

Edited @ 2017-07-12: Updated the Parallel Port link to use the Wayback Archive Machine.

Comment: [Parallel Port link](http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm) no longer shows what you're describing in your answer. Do you have a similar link source?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Updated the link, surprised you did not think of using the wayback machine.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the printer in question have a windows print driver? If so, it doesn't matter that it is printing over LPT1 or not, it is just using the standard Print stuff.

Similar question: [Dot Matrix printing in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246233/dot-matrix-printing-in-c)

Comment: You mean i could just create a Report and send it to that printer?

Comment: If you have a printer driver for the printer (i.e., it shows in in Control Panel/Devices as a printer), yes. Most printers have a generic compatibility mode that will allow them to be used even if you don't have an exact model number match.

Comment: This makes printing of invoices 500% times slower, as it prints text as an image.

Answer (score 1):

If your printer has drivers for Windows, then you can use standard printing techniques.  See Petzold's book [Programming Microsoft Windows with C#](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pwcs/) for a good intro.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just got a dot matrix printer in 2019 and you can still buy the ribbons for £5.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

public class ParallelPrinter
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, FileAccess dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    public static void Print(string text)
    {
        using (SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile("LPT1:", FileAccess.Write, 0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (fileHandle.IsInvalid == true)
                throw new ApplicationException("Printer is Invalid");

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    writer.Write(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No drivers you just need a parallel port, you can get a PCI-e card if you don't have one.