# Send printer control codes using Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

I need to send a sequence of control codes (decimal 27, 112, 0, 25 and 250)  to a USB printer "Epson TM printer" using Powershell.

I would like to put the control codes in decimal in a plain text file. e.g. keys.txt.

Content of keys.txt

```
27
112
0
25
250
```

What is the easiest way to send the control codes to the USB printer?  I am thinking whether I need to create a "Generic / Text only" printer pointing to the same USB port, and then use Out-Printer "Generic / Text only" to send the control codes to it.

I tried

```
gc keys.txt | out-printer "Generic / Text only"
```

but the result was not what I wanted.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should be `able to open a stream to the printer port` and write your commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `open a stream to the printer port` and write your commands

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137036/763026)  you can achieve in C#. Just call or convert this in powershell as explained here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg981616

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\.\LPT1");
sr.Write(0x1b); 
sr.Write('k'); 
sr.Write('1'); 
sr.Write("Hello"); // print in Sans Serif
sr.WriteLine();
sr.Flush();
sr.Close();
```

Comment: But, "writer" starts with a "w" :).

Comment: This does not work. I have an error: FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path.

Comment: May be you can google on that specific error and try differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = [char]0x1B +[char]0x70 + [char]0x00 + [char]0x19 + [char]0xFA
Out-Printer -Name <yourprinter> $s
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I found that if I read the codes from a file, I need to mask them with [char][byte].  However, I just found another problem.  If I send the control codes to the printer using Out-Printer command, there are some extra characters (0a, 20, 30, 33, etc) sent with my own codes to the printer too.  I thought there may be something configurable in the printer driver but I couldn't find any.  The Generic / Text only driver was so simple....  I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: I just found a passthrough printer driver that solved the issue!!  The Windows Generic / Text Only driver is not very good at passing thru....