# Encoding Problem In PrintDocument When Using Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printdocument

I have prepared a text to print with dot matrix printer. The text contains turkish characters like ü,ğ, etc.

When I send this text to the dot matrix printer with .net' s PrintDocument class, the turkish characters on the printed document does not appear correctly. But when I send the same text to Laser printer, there is no problem. How can I solve this problem? thanks for your help.

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
 pd.Print();
```

...

```
 static void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
       Font fnt = new Font("Courier", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
       TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, printText, fnt, new Point(0, 0), SystemColors.ControlText);
       e.HasMorePages = false;
   }
```

Comment: +1 for asking a question involving a dot matrix printer. Wow... does anyone still make printer drivers for those things?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246233/dot-matrix-printing-in-c

Comment: Dotmatrix printers may be with us even after laser printers are forgotten!  How else can you print volume invoices cheaply and with the carbon copy option?